# Is there a default difference between methods with '!' and without, in ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods

Is there a default difference between methods with '!' and without, in ruby?

```
collect v collect!

flatten v flatten!
```

and so on..

Comment: Yes and no. *Conventionally* they're used for methods that mutate internal state, perform operations that affect external state (e.g., write to a database), handle exceptions differently, etc. But the `!` is just part of the method name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *ruby* the main difference is that, the `!` methods are selfish, i.e. they apply the changes to the `self` object. They return `nil`, when no changes are done, while the non-`!` methods create new modified object.

In *Rails* the difference is that, the `!` methods are safe versions of non-`!` methods, that means the `!` methods raises an exception when the code encountered an error during execution, while non-`!` methods just return error state, usually `false` condition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the extra rails info